# Getting duration of Youtube Video for Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, video, google-chrome-extension, youtube

I'm new to `Javascript` and making `Chrome Extensions` (I have experience with `Python`/`Java`), so please be patient with me. I'm trying to make a chrome extension, and one part requires the duration of a youtube video. I know I need to use the `Youtube API`, specifically - `contentDetails.duration` - which returns the length of a video.

I've created the manifest.json file and a `.js` file that contains some basic framework for using the youtube api. My question is, how exactly do I use all the features for the youtube api? Like Do I just set some variable equal to `contentDetails.duration` like `length = contentDetails.duration`? Do I need to input some key somewhere (I got the api key already). Do I put this in the .js file after the `search();` in function `onYouTubeApiLoad()`?

Could someone go into the basics of how to use this method? Thank you so much.

Comment: Do you want to get the duration after user visited the youtube.com? or from any web page

Comment: Just from Youtube

Comment: The question is vague (what does `My question is, how exactly do I use all the features for the youtube api` mean?) and hence unanswerable. Maybe you can improve it by including the actual code. Also, the API isn't the only method, you can also use https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=

Answer (score 0):

The Youtube API you provided is an HTTP API. This means that you have to send an HTTP GET request, and Google's server will reply with a response. The standard way to create HTTP request from Javascript is to use either XMLHTTPRequest or fetch.

You can demo the API here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#try-it

Unfortunately, the APIs are rate-limited and require authentication. To get full access, you have to pay Youtube money. This means that users of your extension won't be able to call the Youtube API.

You're better off having users
 1. Open the web page containing the video
 2. Query the document for the  element
 3. Read the duration property to get the length in seconds.

To see what I mean, try entering the following in the Javascript console of a youtube video page.

`document.querySelector('video').duration`